# Не добавляется пользователь в бд

Tags: mysql, база-данных, javafx

При добавлении пользователя никаких ошибок не выдает, но в самой бд данные не появляются.

```
public class DataBaseHandler {

private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lcsmessanger";
private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "1234";

private Connection connection;

public DataBaseHandler() {
    try {
        // Загрузка драйвера JDBC для MySQL
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Не удалось загрузить драйвер JDBC");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void connect() {
    try {
        // Подключение к базе данных
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Подключение к базе данных выполнено успешно!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void disconnect() {
    try {
        if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
            // Закрытие подключения
            connection.close();
            System.out.println("Отключение от базы данных выполнено успешно!");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Не удалось отключиться от базы данных");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Connection getConnection() {
    return connection;
}


public void addUser(String nikname, String login, String password) {


    String sql = "INSERT  INTO users (nikname, login, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setString(1, nikname);
            statement.setString(2, login);
            statement.setString(3, password);
            System.out.println("Пользователь добавлен");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

```
@FXML
void initialize() {
    reg_btn.setOnAction(event -> {
        singUpUser();
    });

}

private void singUpUser(){
    DataBaseHandler dataBaseHandler = new DataBaseHandler();

    dataBaseHandler.connect();
    dataBaseHandler.addUser(nik_field.getText(), login_field.getText(), password_field.getText());
    dataBaseHandler.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Пробовал добавить connection.commit() в метод addUser Выдает ошибку об автокоммите

Comment: Забыта строчка `statement.executeUpdate()`

Answer (score 0):

Ну конечно , вы забыли

```
statement.executeUpdate()
```